# Advice on workflow on creating and typesetting dictionary (glossary)

Tags: workflow, dictionaries, glossary

I'm trying to write and typesetting a dictionary for a language I am making. As the entry count balooning, I'm getting overwhelmed and I think doing repeating job of sorting and manually making section is not the proper way to do it. Consulting with Google Search is not easy since the term `dictionary` or `glossary` often means other stuff.

I have little experience on SQL but I'm familiar with CSV. I believe the workflow is involving those parts, especially if I want to put a relational notes on some entry as such.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\newcommand{\entry}{2}{\textbf{#1}\ {#2}}

\usepackage{hanging}

\begin{document}
   \begin{hangparas}{1.5em}{1}
   \section{C}
      \entry{cat}{a hell and evil descendant of Alkosh but fluffy and kind creature}
   \section{F}
      \entry{feline}{catfolk living on earth, ranging from big boy to small boy
   \section{J}
      \entry{Jirra}{a small \textbf{feline}, particularly my house cat has dark orange fur. See \textbf{cat, feline, pet} % <--refer to these entries
   \section{P}
      \entry{pet}{good man's friend, I have one. See \textbf{Jirra}} % <-- also this
   \end{hangparas}
\end{document}
```

I believe using this method allows me to have a database usable beyond Latex document. I could use the database for other uses like online dictionary, for example.

I have no experience on setting a real dictionary before but I've been setting a small glossary for a book on InDesign but the work is really conventional and tiring because we had to put every entry one by one and forcing us to keep checking the relational table.

Comment: Are you familiar with the [glossaries package](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.pdf)? See also the [Beginners' Guide](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossariesbegin.pdf) for this package. Also https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Indexing may be of interest.

Comment: @Marijn I have no idea of `glossaries` but it might be a useful start, thank you! 

I'm still open for any suggestions.